# React remix middleware and database connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix, remix.run

I am facing a problem that is Remix doesn't have a middleware before a loader function. In Express we have middlewares to authenticate a user. I am calling `isAuth` function in every loader and action function for authenticating.

```js
export let loader = async ({ request }) => {
  await isAuth(request);
  const users = await getAllUsers();

  return json({ users }, { status: 200 });
};
```

and also I am connecting my database in every utility function.

```js
export const getAllUsers = async () => {
  await dbconnect();
  return await User.find();
};

export const getUser = async (id) => {
  await dbconnect();
  return await User.findById(id);
};
```

So is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently Remix does not have *middleware*, so you will need to authenticate users in each loader. Although middleware is coming soon.

https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/7642

As for database connections, you should be able to reuse the connection by exporting it from another file.

See the *Connect to the database* section of the Remix Jokes tutorial for an example.

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/tutorials/jokes#connect-to-the-database